# Element id and name are visible but not able to click

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on one element and also trying for sendkeys.

I am able to see id and name of the element, but when I am trying to click on it, it is giving me:

> Unable to locate element: #customer_firstname

Check below HTML

```
<input onkeyup="$('#firstname').val(this.value);" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isName" id="customer_firstname" name="customer_firstname" value="" type="text">
```

I have simply tried by id, name and xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("ddddd");
driver.findElement(By.name("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("ddddd");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customer_firstname']")).sendKeys("ddddd");
```

Here is the code

```
driver.get("automationpractice.com/index.php"); driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click(); driver.findElement(By.id("email_create")).sendKeys("test@te‌​st.com"); driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitCreate")).click(); //driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("dsdsd"‌​); driver.findElement(By.name("customer_firstname")).sendKeys(‌​"sadsa");
```

Comment: Is your control actually visible on the page when it fails?  You may need to use an explicit wait for the control.
Is your control embedded in an iframe?  If so, you would need to switch to that frame first.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I tried explicit wait. Also tried till element is visible but it return 0

Comment: @SakshiRaina this is different issue. even if I try to enter in driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("dsdsd"); which having html <input id="firstname" class="form-control" name="firstname" value="" type="text">   it giving meelement not found

Comment: would it be possible to share a link to the page in question?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("email_create")).sendKeys("test@test.com");
 driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitCreate")).click();
 //driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("dsdsd");
 driver.findElement(By.name("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("sadsa");

Comment: got solution thanks all